# What does the "Next" flag indicate on GitLab top bar?

Tags: gitlab

This morning when I logged into GitLab I noticed this "Next" flag on the top bar:

[image]

It appears whether I am logged in or not. **What does "Next" indicate?**

A Google search turns up nothing. It doesn't appear in any GitLab screen shots I am able to find either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the canary version of Gitlab you are being served, you can find out more here: https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/engineering/#canary-testing

You can swap the version of Gitlab you see here: https://next.gitlab.com/?nav_source=navbar

The reasoning behind providing the Canary versions to users either at random or by those who have opt-ed in:

> GitLab makes use of a 'Canary' stage. Production Canary is a series of
>   servers running GitLab code in production environment. The Canary
>   stage contains code functional elements like web, container registry
>   and git servers while sharing data elements such as sidekiq, database,
>   and file storage with production. This allows UX code and most
>   application logic code to be consumed by smaller subset of users under
>   real world scenarios before being made available to all users on
>   GitLab.com.

Comment: This makes sense, except on next.gitlab.com the toggle is set to "current," and the flag appears regardless of whether I'm logged in.

Comment: @LShaver could be a bug in that case either in the display of the badge or not allowing you to opt out.

Comment: @LShaver There is currently a bug open for the persistent badge, you can view more info here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/61550

Comment: Awesome thanks for the insight. This was hard to find because it is literally the word `next`, and the search `next to gitlab logo` and its derivatives did not give me any results. I only found this answer when I was asking my own similar question.

Comment: @danielsmith1789 yeah it's a weird one to track down, I used the approach of inspecting the html to see what the markup was, the badge had a class of 'canary' so then I realized it's probably a release version so googled 'Gitlab canary next' and that detail came up.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is interesting that the link shows up, but the landing page with the switch does not have any information at all about what the switch does